# How to uninstall a package installed from snapcraft?

Tags: snap

I used this command line

```
sudo snap install pwgen-tyhicks
```

to install pwgen but I can't findout how to use it.
So I want to uninstall it. How to  uninstall it?

Answer (score 275):

```
sudo snap remove pwgen-tyhicks
```

[From documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started):

> Prior to removal (except on Ubuntu Core systems), a snap’s internal user, system, and configuration data is saved as a snapshot (snapd 2.39+), and retained for 31 days. A snapshot can be used to restore the state of your snap upon reinstallation.

Answer (score 30):

## Purge

Use `sudo snap remove --purge snapname` to completely remove a snap package, including all of its **revision loop drives.** Only by doing so, will the hard drive space be made available again, as demonstrated below for the snap package `firefox`.

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME     TYPE   SIZE    MODEL    SERIAL    WWN    MOUNTPOINT
…
loop6    loop  70.4M                              /snap/core22/275
loop7    loop 176.9M                              /snap/firefox/1810
loop8    loop 178.4M                              /snap/firefox/1860
loop9    loop 346.3M                              /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
…
```

```bash
$ snap list
Name       Version    Rev    Tracking         Publisher    Notes
firefox    105.0-2    1860   latest/stable    mozilla✓     -
```

Here is the command that performs the purge:

```bash
$ sudo snap remove --purge firefox
```

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME     TYPE   SIZE    MODEL    SERIAL    WWN    MOUNTPOINT
…
loop6    loop  70.4M                              /snap/core22/275
loop9    loop 346.3M                              /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
…
```

Comment: Note that you may need to reinstall snap first to purge its data

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo snap remove pwgen-tyhicks --purge
```

Uninstall completely

Comment: After using `snap remove --purge` the app is still in my launcher but its icon is gone, and it still works when I click on its empty box.  It doesn't appear in the `snap list` list either.  Anyone have any ideas?